# Open a new tab in gnome-terminal and have it automatically connect via ssh

Tags: command-line, ssh, tabs

I find myself ssh-ing into another machine a lot at work.  So much so, that I use it more than simply using the terminal on my own desktop.

I know that (normally) when I open a new tab, it will change the directory to be in the same folder that I am currently in.  Is there any way to have it check to see if I'm ssh'd into another machine and, if so, ssh into that machine as well so that I don't have to key in the host, port, and flags for the new ssh with each open tab?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

gnome-terminal → edit → profile preferences → title and command → run a custom command instead of my shell

you might want to make a new profile for using the local shell.

you can choose the default profile in edit → profiles

if you have to specify passwords when connecting over ssh, set up private/public key authentication.

Comment: That was perfect.  Thanks!  Also, would you happen to know how to clear the screen of the output after running that command?  I tried just using an `ssh ... && clear` at the end but that raises an error.

Comment: && is bourne shell, it is not a command. you could do ``sh -c "ssh .. && clear"``

Comment: That appears to run, but not actually remove the output.

Comment: why not just set "when command exits" to "exit the terminal"?

Comment: I was wanting to supress what I thought was a message from ssh whenever I connected, but it actually appears to be a banner from the machine I'm connecting to.  I think it's a separate problem entirely now.  Thanks!